# SSMS - MS SQL Sever Query option set ON/OFF to display all columns in Shortdate format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, format

In SSMS, for `MS SQL Server 2008` or newer versions, is there a general query option or something like that, something to set ON or OFF before launching the query, in order to view all `DATE columns` as `Shortdate` (only date, without time)?
Something `like SET ANSI_NULLS { ON | OFF }` ?

Because I often use `'select * from table'`, or different approaches like that, and inside tables are many columns and the `DATE columns` are in different places, and I don't want every time to check where these `columns` are and to explicitly use `CONVERT` or `CAST` only on them, to display them properly.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: This is not a database question, but an interface question.  What tool are you using to access the database?

Comment: You're right. DrHouseofSQL already assumed corectly:
SSMS

Comment: There may be a registry key that provides the date and time formats used by SSMS, but some fiddling about with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) didn't make it leap out for me. If it follows the system locale settings then you might be able to change the registry entry for the time format to an empty string.

Comment: I've added a little more to my post, as I felt it was relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I will solve such situation from interface end only.

Also saying like,

> Because I often use 'select * from table', or different approaches

this is itself bad,you can't have your own way or approaches.

Nonetheless in sql we can do something like this,

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
    GO

    --proc parameter
    DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(50) = 'Employee'
    DECLARE @table_schema VARCHAR(50) = 'HumanResources'
    --local variable
    DECLARE @Columnname VARCHAR(max) = ''
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(max) = ''

    SELECT @Columnname = @Columnname + CASE 
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'date'
                OR DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
                THEN 'cast(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' as date)'
            ELSE QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
            END + ',' + CASE 
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'date'
                OR DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
                THEN 'cast(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' as date)'
            ELSE QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
            END + ','
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

    SET @Columnname = STUFF(@Columnname, len(@Columnname), 1, '')
    --set @Columnname=stuff(@Columnname,1,1,'')
    --PRINT @Columnname
    SET @Sql = 'select ' + @Columnname + ' from ' + @table_schema + '.' + @tablename + ''

    --PRINT @Sql
    EXEC (@Sql)
```

it can be further improve as per requirement.Also please use `sp_executeSql`
you can customize case condition.

Comment: Personally, I'd change `'[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'` to `QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)`. Just covers all possible names.

Comment: That comes close to what I want. But just close. Entirely it would be an option something in SSMS.
In others DB IDEs are such options available? (Oracle, MySQL, etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "magic" display format button or function in SSMS no. When you execute a query, SSMS will display that column in the format that is appropriate for that data type; for a `datetime` field that will **include** the time.

If you don't want to include the time, then you have to either `CAST` or `CONVERT` the individual column(s), or format the data appropriately in your presentation layer (for example, if you're using Excel then dd/MM/yyyy may be appropriate).

If all your columns have `'00:00:00.000'` at the end of their value, the problem isn't the display format, it's your data type choice. Clearly, the problem isn't that SSMS is returning a time for a `date**time**` column, it's that you've declare a column as a `datetime` when it should have been a `date`. You can change the datatype of a column using `ALTER`. For example:

```
USE Sandbox;
Go

CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID smallint IDENTITY(1,1), DateColumn datetime);

INSERT INTO TestTable (DateColumn)
VALUES ('20180201'),('20180202'),('20180203'),('20180204'),('20180205');

SELECT *
FROM TestTable;
GO

ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN DateColumn date;
GO

SELECT *
FROM TestTable;
GO

DROP TABLE TestTable;
```

TL;DR: SSMS displays data in an appropriate format for the data you have. If you don't like it, you have to supply an alternate format for it to display for each appropriate column. If the issue is your data, change the data type.

---

Edit: I wanted to add a little more to this.

This question is very much akin to also asking "I would like to be able to run queries where decimals only return the integer part of the value. Can this be done automagically?". So, the value 9.1 would return 9, but also, the value 9.999999999 would return 9.

Now, I realise that you "might" be thinking "Numbers aren't anything like dates", but really, they are. At the end of the (especially in data) a date is just a number (hell, a `datetime` time in SQL Server is stored as the number of days after `1900-01-01`, and the time is a decimal of that number, so `43136.75` is actually `2018-02-07 18:00:00.000`).

Now that we're talking in numbers, does it seems like a *good* idea to you to have all your decimals returned as their `FLOOR` value? I imagine the answer is "no". Imagine if you were doing some kind of accounting, and only summing the values of transactions using the `FLOOR` value. You could be losing 1,000's (or more) of £/$/€'s.

Think of the old example of the people who stole money from payments which contained values of less than a penny. The amount they stole was a huge amount, however, not one individual theft had a value >= $0.01. The same principle really rules here; precision is very important and if your column has that precision it *should* be there for a reason.

The same is true for dates. If you are storing times with dates, and the time isn't relevant for that specific query, change your query; having a setting to *ignore* times (or decimal points) is, in all honestly, just a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an option like this in SSMS. The best thing I am coming up with is to create views of the tables and this way you can do a

```
select convert(date, <date column>)
```

one time and they will appear as just dates in the views.

Comment: Means specify them (the columns). I don't wanna do that, like I said...

Comment: Understood, you would only have to do it once, then the view is created. If you can verify that there is no option to do what you need in the setting of SSMS then it may be your only choice....

Comment: I make short and rapid queries, on various tables / databases. In an environment like that when you often change the object of interrogation, it can be very useful to change that in SSMS as an option in order not to have a so large date column displayed, especially if normally you are not interested on time values (and on the time part of the date column there are just '00:00:00.000').